# Installing cloudera impala without cloudera manager

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, impala

Kindly provide the link for installing the imapala in ubuntu without cloudera manager. Couldn't able to install with official link.

Unable to locate package impala using these queries :

```
sudo apt-get install impala             # Binaries for daemons
sudo apt-get install impala-server      # Service start/stop script
sudo apt-get install impala-state-store # Service start/stop script
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First you need to get the list of packages and store it in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, then update the packages, **then** you fire the Impala queries.

At the terminal do the following:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/impala/ubuntu/precise/amd64/impala/cloudera.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install impala             # Binaries for daemons
sudo apt-get install impala-server      # Service start/stop script
sudo apt-get install impala-state-store # Service start/stop script
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you installed the correct list file?
See "Packages and Repositories" on page 14.
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Impala/latest/PDF/Installing-and-Using-Impala.pdf

Comment: 404 - exactly the problem with link-only answers, always try to include essential parts to make your answer valuable even in case of a link becoming a deadlink