# installing Cloudera Impala without installing CDH?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala

I'm using pure Apache Hadoop with Hive. I need to install Apache Impala, for integrate with Hive and Kudu. I'm trying to install with source from [this](https://impala.apache.org/downloads.html) link and with [this build instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IMPALA/Building+Impala). In this page said that, "build Impala from source and how to configure and run Impala in a single node development environment."

Can I use Apache Impala source for production environment with pure Apache Hadoop(not Cloudera)? I also see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146504/installing-cloudera-impala-without-cloudera-manager) from other stack-overflow question. In this page answer, recommended that using package for installing. But the dependencies of this packages is HBase, Hadoop etc CDH.

Can anyone show how to install Apache Impala without Cloudera Hadoop and inside the Apache Hadoop(pure) in production environment?

Thanks.

Comment: What issues are you having with existing build/install instructions? But why do you need to build instead of download the latest/stable release?

Comment: This is my big problem! There is no perfect tutorial to install it on Apache Hadoop.